# Sending multiple variables by email with jquery/ajax & php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am baffled by trying to get a jquery/ajax form to post data and get it sent by email to php.

Here is the JQuery:

```
$( "#sendbut3" ).click(function() {
var ntext = $( "#smallfield3" ).val();
var ptext = $( "#smallfield2" ).val();
var q1text = $( "#smallfield1" ).val();
$.ajax({
    url: '/send.php',
    type: 'post', 
    data: {ntext: ntext, ptext: ptext, q1text: q1text},
});
return false;
});
```

This is the PHP:

```
<?php

$email_to = "myemailaddress@gmail.com";
$email_from = "website@domain.com";
$email_message = $_POST["ntext", "ptext", "q1text"];
$email_subject = "query from web form";
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
```

Can anyone please point to my mistake?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: So is the email being sent?

Comment: `$_POST["ntext", "ptext", "q1text"];` That won't work.

Comment: Nothing comes through at all... I suspect the problem is the way I've written the variables (data: line on the jquery and 4th line down on the PHP)

Comment: See the answer Marc B gave @Pete

Answer (score 3):

Basic PHP arrays: You need to learn them:

```
$email_message = $_POST["ntext", "ptext", "q1text"];
```

is totally invalid. You cannot use multiple keys like that.

```
$ntext = $_POST['ntext'];
$ptext = $_POST['ptext'];
$qltext = $_POST['qltext'];
```

would be more acceptable, assuming your JS code actually produces key:value pairs like that.

What you have is a flat-out syntax error and could not possibly ever work:

```
php > $foo = array('a' => 'b', 'c' => 'd');
php > echo $foo['a', 'b'];
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ']' in php shell code on line 1
```

Comment: So the first thing to do is check for errors.
I'm not a phpist, but I know there is a function to activate them or something.

Comment: error_reporting and display_errors. neither should ever be off while debugging/developing.

Comment: I don't know how to do any of that. And yes I need to learn arrays, what they are and how to use them.

Comment: So start with the official docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: If I replace line 4 of the PHP with the three lines you suggest, how will the email know what to contain?

Comment: email doesn't "know" anything. You need to **TELL** the email string what it should contain. If you're going to treat programming languages as `$foo = world of warcraft` and think that PHP can instantly implement the entirety of WoW for you, you're going to have a very very very bad time learning programming.

Comment: How do you tell the email string what to contain? Or in other words, how would I say "$email_message = "$ntext $ptext $a1text"?

Comment: pretty much exactly like that: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: $email_message = $ntext . $ptext . $qltext;
or any arrangement you want for your message

Comment: Thanks for the help so far - I've made the changes as you suggest and still no luck. Could it be this line?
    data: {ntext: ntext, ptext: ptext, q1text: q1text},
There are 3 variables set already with these names. Maybe they are not global variables? If not, how can I check?